# Exception with ICEFaces

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I'm using ICEFaces. I have datatable with multiple columns. One I load the page I get the following exception; however, the page still loads and contiues correctly but after I start pagination the table it's slow, I'm not sure what this exception is about as the page still work and I'm not sure if it's related to the slowness of pagination.

Any ideas?

THanks,

Tam

The Excpetion:

```
15:27:49,254 ERROR [Digester] Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.TagToComponentMap.addTags(TagToComponentMap.java:145)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.JsfJspDigester.startPrefixMapping(JsfJspDigester.java:126)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startNamespaceMapping(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1785)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:464)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet$ThreadBlockingRequestResponse.respondWith(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:36)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:76)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:139)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:52)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:114)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:160)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher$1.service(SessionDispatcher.java:42)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.service(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:19)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.service(EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.java:63)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:62)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: You spelled "expection", "exception", and "excpetion" all in the same question :p

Comment: yead I do have spelling issues :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to diagnose anything without seeing any code, but it looks like this has been covered before in other places.  Have you at least tried Google'ing that error?  Here is a definition of the error you're seeing from [this](http://marc.info/?l=xerces-j-user&m=117066285728163&w=2) message board thread:

*This means you have something before the root element which is not permitted to appear there according to the XML spec. Make sure that NOTHING comes before the XML declaration except the
optional byte-order mark, and that NOTHING comes between the XML declaration and the outermost element except comments, processing instructions, and whitespace.*

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I noticed though is that the broswer CPU usage go to 100% once I start pagination! and the server seems to have finished responding. I don't think it's an issue from the server. Sometimes the browser will ask me if I want to stop the script because it has been running long! It might be some JS with ICEFaces that is getting stuck. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a simple syntax problem if you use Facelets. The XML parser (Xerces) tells you that there are parts in the page that are not allowed. This can be the cause for the behavior.

But, as mentioned above, we need a detailled look at the page markup.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a JSP problem. You need to provide more information. You're also better off asking the ICEFaces forum.

Comment: -2 for suggesting that Tam ask the question in ICEFaces forum where the ICEFaces developers lurk and are helpful to people to raise issues? Man...